# Destroy command doesn't work on particle systems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I shoot with my gun (Which sends the TakeDamage function) the barrel explodes
First it becomes invisible and after 2.1s it gets destroyed.
But the particle System which is supposed to be destroyed in 2s continues on looping.

Here's the code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    public ParticleSystem explode;

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        ParticleSystem PartClone = Instantiate(explode, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        PartClone.Play();


        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        ParticleSystem.Destroy(PartClone, 2f);
        Destroy(gameObject, 2.1f);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `ParticleSystem explode` to a GameObject (prefab) that contains this particle effect.

Instantiate it with `GameObject PartClone = Instantiate(...)`.

Destroy it with `Destroy(PartClone, 2f)`.

---

The full code should look like this. In your particle prefab, set the ParticleSystem PlayOnAwake property to true, so you don't need to call `Play()` after instantiating.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    public GameObject explode;

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        GameObject PartClone = Instantiate(explode, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);    

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(PartClone, 2f);
        Destroy(gameObject, 2.1f);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tysm! And how do I make the particle system invisible at the beginning?

Comment: Well, it depends. If you just want it to start in a certain moment, set `PlayOnAwake` to false in the particle system of the prefab and after you instantiate the prefab, call `PartClone.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play()` when you want it to play.

Comment: But if you want the particles themselves to be invisible at the beginning, you can set the property "Color over lifetime" of the particle system to be invisible (alpha = 0) in the start of the particle's life and go to some color after.